# Python remove punctuation from text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a thousand line Italian text and creating a dictionary of unique words.
I have tried two methods of removing the punctuation:
using string

```
for p in string.punctuation:
     word = word.replace(p, str())
```

or :

```
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        stripped_text =""
        for char in word:
            if char in '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~>><<<<?>>?123456789':
               char = ''
               stripped_text += char
```

My problem is that this still contains punctuation:

```
{'<<Dicerolti': 1,'piage>>.': 1,'succia?>>.': 1,…}
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Sorry the returned dictionary did not come out correctly: {'<<Dicerolti': 1, 'affetti,': 2, 'porta:': 1, 'porta;': 1, 'dubbiosi': 1, 'Palazzo': 1, 'quei,': 3, 'Felice!': 1, 'traccia>>.': 1, 'Nacqui': 1, 'angelo': 1, 'condotta.': 1, 'i': 258, 'voi': 91, 'digiunto.': 1, 'quei:': 1, 'porta.': 2, 'porta,': 5, 'via.': 2, 'consorto': 1, 'via,': 14, 'fosca,': 1, 'vince': 10, 'Lancialotto': 1, 'fosca!': 1, 'vinci': 2, 'voi?>>;': 1,

Comment: You can [edit] your question to update information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Thank you for this. I have looked at the solutions in your reference, but I am somewhat lost. I am wondering whether the specific punctuation that is not removed is 'peculiar' to Italian, particularly << and >>. These replace " and " in English. I tried word.translate(None, string.punctuation), but get a Type Error. TAkes one argument, two given. Also in the dictionary above porta returns four times , once porta; and then porta:, porta. and porta,. So my argument falls away rather. Need more help if possible, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the re module for this and a little printf style trick to build a regex that flags any punctuation for replacement.

```
import string
import re
a = '>>some_crazy_string..!'
print re.sub('[%s]' % string.punctuation,'',a)
```

prints out

> somecrazystring

I've used this trick a couple of times for 'anonymizing' log files.